# Doing something doesn't work the first time, but the second time does work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

So I am making my simple calculator, any this is what I have so far:

```
import time
print ("Welcome. This is a calculator that uses the function: A (operator) B.")
time.sleep(3.5)
print ("Available operators include: Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division,     Exponent, and Remainder division.")
time.sleep(3.5)
while True:
    a = float(input("Type in a value of A. "))
    b = float(input("Type in a value of B. "))
    opera = input("Would you like to: Add - Subtract - Multiply - Divide - Exponent - or Remainder? ")
    opera = opera.lower()
    while not (opera) == "add" or (opera) == "subtract" or (opera) == "multiply" or (opera) == "divide" or (opera) == "exponent" or (opera) == "remainder":
        print ("Invalid operation.")
        opera = input("Would you like to: Add - Subtract - Multiply - Divide - Exponent - or Remainder? ")
        break
    if (opera) == "add":
        print ((a) + (b))
    if (opera) == "subtract":
        print ((a) - (b))
    if (opera) == "multiply":
        print ((a) * (b))
    if (opera) == "divide":
        print ((a) / (b))
    if (opera) == "exponent":
        print ((a) ** (b))
    if (opera) == "remainder":
        print ((a) % (b))
    cont = input("Would you like to do another problem?")
    cont = cont.lower()
    if cont != "yes":
        break
    quit
```

So, when I start the calculator and put in values for a and b, putting anything except add will result in invalid operation. It will then prompt me to put a valid operation, and then it works for all of the operations. How can I fix that? I'm assuming the problem has to do with the while not inside the while true.

Comment: You don't need all those parenthesis. It's cleaner to use `if opera`, `print(a / b)` etc

Comment: he doesn't need the sleeps either, and the while loop isn't going to work the way he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a parenthetical issue.

```
 while not (opera) == "add" or (opera) == "subtract" or (opera) == "multiply" or (opera) == "divide" or (opera) == "exponent" or (opera) == "remainder":
```

Should be

```
 while not ((opera) == "add" or (opera) == "subtract" or (opera) == "multiply" or (opera) == "divide" or (opera) == "exponent" or (opera) == "remainder"):
```

Your not is only applying to the first term, "add".
The reason it works after that is you never return to the while not conditional because of the break.

I'd look at dictionaries as a much more elegant way to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually numerous problems with your script. See the modifications I made below:

operations = ('add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'exponent', 'remainder')

print ("Welcome. This is a calculator that uses the function: A (operator) B. \n")
print ("Available operators include: {0}".format(operations))

while True:
    a = float(raw_input("Type in a value of A. "))
    b = float(raw_input("Type in a value of B. "))

```
opera = raw_input("Which operation would you like to perform? ")
opera = opera.lower()

while opera not in operations:
    print ("Invalid operation.")
    opera = raw_input("Which operation would you like to perform? ")

if opera == "add":
    print (a + b)
if opera == "subtract":
    print (a - b)
if (opera) == "multiply":
    print (a * b)
if (opera) == "divide":
    print (a / b)
if (opera) == "exponent":
    print (a ** b)
if (opera) == "remainder":
    print (a % b)

if raw_input("Would you like to do another problem?").lower() != 'yes':
    break
```

Issue 0: sleep statements are always anooying from a user perspective, and it added 7 second to a test debug run. Get rid of them. And if you really... really... want them, add them back in when you're done.

Issue 1: You used the input function instead of the raw_input function. [Read the python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), the input function executes an eval statement on whatever you input. I got a NameError raised when I tried to execute the 'add' command. Use raw_input instead.

Issue 2: Your logic was wrong in the while statement. You could have said while (opera != 'add) or ... but I opted to just add all of the valid values to a tuple. It's cleaner, and neater that way. Also the logic to break out of the loop was wrong. Regardless of the input you will break out of the loop, you might as well ahve used a if statement for the same effect.

Issue 3: This screams c style switch statement, so use a dictionary. I'd use a dictionary to tie the string form o fthe operations (e.g. 'add', 'multiply') to the function ponters. It'd be a lot clear and more pythonic. I can post the code for using a dictionary if you want.

Comment: The questioner is using Python 3.x - `raw_input` was renamed to `input` and `input` was removed.